# Rx Java : replay() autoconnect() not being subscribed

Tags: rx-java, observable, reactive-programming

I am quite new to Rx-java and i am trying to understand how `replay() autoConnect()` would work. I have the following situation in my code and I want to make the expensive operation more efficient.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Single<String> observable = getStringObservable().observeOn(Schedulers.io()).toSingle();
    Single<String> observable1 = getStringObservable().observeOn(Schedulers.io()).toSingle();
    String observable2 = getStringObservable().toSingle().toBlocking().value();

    observable.subscribe(s -> System.out.println("Sub1 got: " + s));
    observable1.subscribe(s -> System.out.println("Sub2 got: " + s));
    System.out.println("Sub3 got " + observable2);
}

//This is some expensive operation which is a network call
private static Observable<String> getStringObservable() {
    return Single.just("Event")
                .map(s -> {
                    System.out.println("Expensive operation for " + s);
                    return s;
                }).toObservable().replay().autoConnect();
}
```

The output of the code is -

```
Expensive operation for Event
Expensive operation for Event
Sub1 got: Event
Expensive operation for Event
Sub3 got Event
Sub2 got: Event
```

What I am looking for being more efficient is -

```
Expensive operation for Event
Sub1 got: Event
Sub2 got Event
Sub3 got: Event
```

My understanding of replay autoConnect is it would save the response for subscribers. I tried with `autoConnect(3)` since I have three subscribers but it dosen't seem to be working.

Some assumptions - The code above is a pseudo code of how my code really is. In my actual code all three observable are located in different workflows and can be called in any sequence like observable >> observable1 >> observable2 OR observable2 >> observable >> observable1 and so forth.

I cannot be storing a state of any observable in my code that can be shared.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cache the operation, but you'd have to keep a reference to the observable, like this:

```
ConnectableObservable<String> cachedObservable = Observable.just("Event")
        .map(s -> {
            System.out.println("Expensive operation for " + s);
            return s;
        }).replay();
cachedObservable.connect();

Single<String> observable = cachedObservable.observeOn(Schedulers.io()).singleOrError();
Single<String> observable1 = cachedObservable.observeOn(Schedulers.io()).singleOrError();
String observable2 = cachedObservable.singleOrError().blockingGet();

observable.subscribe(s -> System.out.println("Sub1 got: " + s));
observable1.subscribe(s -> System.out.println("Sub2 got: " + s));
System.out.println("Sub3 got " + observable2);
```

Prints

```
Expensive operation for Event
Sub1 got: Event
Sub2 got: Event
Sub3 got Event
```

If you truly want to have this as a cache for your network operation, you can use [Guava's `memoize`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html#memoizeWithExpiration(com.google.common.base.Supplier,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) to cache the observable for some time:

```
Supplier<ConnectableObservable<String>> cache = Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration(() -> {
    ConnectableObservable<String> cached = Observable.just("Event")
            .map(s -> {
                System.out.println("Expensive operation for " + s);
                return s;
            }).replay();
    cached.connect();
    return cached;
}, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

cache.get().subscribe(thing -> doAwesomeStuffWith(thing));
```

Comment: It worked for me. I was able to get it working with the snippet you posted before.Thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

You need 3 subscribers but you only create some flows and then block on the first consumer, which will prevent the other 2 subscribers from ever subscribing. Subscribe with the non-blocking ones first, then with the blocking one:

```java
Single<String> observable = getStringObservable().observeOn(Schedulers.io()).toSingle();
Single<String> observable1 = getStringObservable().observeOn(Schedulers.io()).toSingle();

observable.subscribe(s -> System.out.println("Sub1 got: " + s));
observable1.subscribe(s -> System.out.println("Sub2 got: " + s));

String observable2 = getStringObservable().toSingle().toBlocking().value();

System.out.println("Sub3 got " + observable2);
```

Comment: +1 this is great, in my code the order of operation can by random, like
observable >> observable1 >> observable2 or
observable2 >> observable >> observable1 and so on... 
How do i handle in that case?

Comment: Also I tried as you suggested with `replay().autoConnect(3)` it still stuck.

Comment: Don't block and rethink your subscription logic.

Comment: I agree I think thats the best solution for this problem :)